# How do I make a cloned spinner control the correct input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, clone, jquery-ui-spinner

I am trying to dynamically change the number of [jQuery UI spinners](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/). I have no problem removing them, however when adding a new one, what I'm doing is cloning the first one and appending it to the end like this:

```
function clone_elem() {
    $("#num_people").append($(".num_people").first().clone(true, true));
}
```

Everything seems to work correctly, however the cloned spinner elements control the original spinner text value instead of the cloned one. How can I make the cloned spinners control the correct input box? Perhaps I should be using something other than [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for this?

[Here's my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XuvmR/2/) so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clone an element with a spinner, what you want to do is remove the old spinner(s), clone the element, then re-add the spinners:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    make_spinners();
    clone_elem();
});

function clone_elem() {
    kill_spinners();
    $("#num_people").append($(".num_people").first().clone(true, true));
    make_spinners();
}

function kill_spinners() {
    $('.spinner').spinner( "destroy" );
}

function make_spinners() {
    if ($('.spinner').length > 0) {
        $('.spinner').spinner({
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                // Apply the JS when the value is changed
                if (typeof $(this).get(0).onkeyup == "function") {
                    $(this).get(0).onkeyup.apply($(this).get(0));
                }
                if (typeof $(this).get(0).onchange == "function") {
                    $(this).get(0).onchange.apply($(this).get(0));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here it is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XuvmR/10/).

**Edit:**

Note if you are dynamically adding and removing spinners, going, for example, from 49 spinners to 50 spinners can actually take 3-4 seconds on a fairly decent PC. Instead of destroying *all* of the old spinner(s), you can just destroy the spinners on the object you are cloning, which will speed things up significantly (takes ~300 ms). The actual object duplication is almost instantaneous; what takes a long time is re-applying all the spinners. So this is what I'm doing now in my production script:

```
// Destroy spinner on object to be cloned
$elem.find('.spinner').spinner( "destroy" );

var $clone;

// Add new clone(s)
while (cur_number < desired_number) {
    $clone = $elem.clone(false, true);
    $("#where_to_put_it").append($clone);

    // Increment IDs
    $clone.find("*").each(function() {
        var id = this.id || "";
        var match = id.match(/^(.*)(\d)+$/i) || [];
        if (match.length == 3) {
            this.id = match[1] + (cur_rooms + 1);
        }
    });

    cur_number++;
}

// Re-apply the spinner thingy to all objects that don't have it
$('.spinner').spinner({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        // Apply the JS when the value is changed
        if (typeof $(this).get(0).onkeyup == "function") {
            $(this).get(0).onkeyup.apply($(this).get(0));
        }
        if (typeof $(this).get(0).onchange == "function") {
            $(this).get(0).onchange.apply($(this).get(0));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The cloned elements events are still pointing at the first element.

Here it is with a function to create new spinner elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/XuvmR/9/

```
function clone_elem() {
    $("#num_people").append(makespinner());
    if ($('.spinner').length > 0) {
        $('.spinner').spinner({
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                // Apply the JS when the value is changed
                if (typeof $(this).get(0).onkeyup == "function") {
                    $(this).get(0).onkeyup.apply($(this).get(0));
                }
                if (typeof $(this).get(0).onchange == "function") {
                    $(this).get(0).onchange.apply($(this).get(0));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

function makespinner() {
    if (typeof g === 'undefined') {
        g = {};
    }
    if (typeof g.uniqueID === 'undefined') {
        g.uniqueID = 2;
    }
    var base = $('<div class="num_people">');
    var held = $('<p class="spinner_p">');
    held.appendTo(base);
    var nextID = g.uniqueID++;
    $('<label for="' + "num_adults_" + nextID + '" class="label required">Number of people: </label>').appendTo(held);
    $('<input id="' + "num_adults_" + nextID + '" type="text" name="' + "num_adults_" + nextID + '" value="2" class="spinner" />').appendTo(held);
    return base;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the delete advice.  Took it down while it was incomplete.  Done now.

Comment: This is a great answer and actually gave me an idea for a better solution, which I will post in a minute. I would accept this, however the strings are internationalized, so coding the text in the JS would be a pain and I wouldn't want duplicate strings for the translators to have to translate. So instead, I'll upvote you.

Comment: You can clone without events.  Change the attributes. Then apply the .spinner()?

Comment: Close, you have to actually remove all the current spinners. I just tried it without removing them and it doesn't work, even without events.